# The “Guided Access is Enabled" message appears with every HTML form submission in iOS 8

Tags: ios, forms, ios8, iphone-standalone-web-app, guided-access

I have a website set as a "home screen" app and accessed via Guided Access. The site contains a form. A message will appear every time there is an HTML form submission: "Guided Access is Enabled. Triple-click the home button to exit." This message is unexpected because all the user has done is submit a form.

This seems to be a new UI bug with iOS 8. During test of the same app with iOS 7 we did not see this issue at all.

There are a couple of [similar](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6847783) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744534/alert-displayed-when-tapping-links-in-uiwebview-with-guided-access-enabled-under) and I've filed a [bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/19958120) with Apple, but I'm wondering if anyone has found a work-around to suppress the message?

Here are two simple pages if you want to try to reproduce this issue:

1. http://jsbin.com/wecipi/1/
2. http://jsbin.com/mohira/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced this bug with our app based on UIWebView. It is a bug in iOS 8 (I've seen others experience the same problem, and we've all filed reports to Apple).

For our app, our development team transforms all requests (only when Guided Access is enabled) with navigation type "UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked" to navigation type "UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther". This will restrict the message from appearing for most links.

You could try to do the same thing with "Form Submitted" and "Form Resubmitted" type links, though our development team believes doing so could potentially cause an error with loading the page (though I'm not sure if we ever tried it).

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear others a filing bugs for this, too. Hopefully they fix this! I've seen the work around you mention, but unfortunately my scenario involves a website, not a native app, so it won't work for. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Mattio You could let the people who created the app you're using know about the issue, maybe they'd implement the workaround for you in their app's code?

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` to `WKWebView` ... works!

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a native app. It's a website set as a home screen app. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html